# How do I remove elements in an array while iterating

Tags: javascript

```
let k = ['adb','dc', 'asd', 'ew'];
let removeIndex = [0,2];
```

I'm struggling to try to figure out how I can programmatically remove elements in k using the indexes listed in removeIndex.

```
let copy = k.slice();

removeIndex.forEach(i=> {
   copy.splice(i,1)
})
```

copy => I don't get my desired result of : ['dc', 'ew']

Comment: You would have to decrement and not increment the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding `splice` - it'll mutate the copy *while* you're depending on the `removeIndex` indicies to continue to correspond to the indicies of the *original* array. After you've removed one element, it won't work as expected.

Try using `.filter` instead, and check to see if the index of the current item being iterated over is included in the `removeIndex` array:

```js
let k = ['adb','dc', 'asd', 'ew'];
let removeIndex = [0,2];
const copy = k.filter((_, i) => !removeIndex.includes(i));
console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to order your removeindex in descending order, in your case `[2,0]` before you call the `forEach` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If `removeIndex` contains the index value in ascending order then you can have a simple `for` loop in descending order of the `removeIndex` elements so that the element from the last is removed first from the `copy` array.

```js
let k = ['adb','dc', 'asd', 'ew'];
let removeIndex = [0,2];
let copy = k.slice();
for(var i=removeIndex.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   copy.splice(removeIndex[i],1);
}
console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple solution using Array.filters from ES6:

```
const words = ['adb','dc', 'asd', 'ew'];
const result = words.filter(word => word.length < 3);

console.log(result);
// expected output: ["dc", "ew"]
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a small function that I've to create and worked fine for me.

for example :

```
let k = ['adb','dc', 'asd', 'ew'];
// you can get the length of the array
let length = k.length;
let array_splice = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
   // you can add your condition here, then
   if (i % 2 == 1) {
       array_splice.push(k[i]);
   }
}
console.log(array_splice); // or return array_splice if you use it to a function;
```

Hope that was helpful for you
see you soon